# How to insert points on top of bar charts using Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Given the illustration

[image]

I was able to create the chart (without the points) using the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

      var chart;

      function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Y', 'Series 1','Series 2'],
          ["Element A", 44,11],
          ["Element B", 31,11],
          ["Element C", 12,11],
        ]);

        var options = {
          bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          axes: {
            x: {
              0: { side: 'bottom', label: 'X'} // Top x-axis.
            }
          }
        };

        var div = document.getElementById('top_x_div');
        var link = document.getElementById('url');
        chart = new google.charts.Bar(div);
        chart.draw(data, options);
        //console.log(chart.getImageURI());
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top_x_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**How to insert points on top of bar charts using Google Charts?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there were a couple ways I thought of, to accomplish...

1. Use a Combo chart
2. Add the points manually, on the chart's `'ready'` event

however, neither option can be achieved using a *material* chart.

```
google.charts.Bar
```

first, *material* charts do not support Combo charts.
and, *material* charts do not have the [methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#methods) necessary to add the points manually.

not to mention, there are also several options that *material* charts do not support.
see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

so we must use a *classic* chart...

```
google.visualization.BarChart
```

there is an option we can use to give the *classic* chart a **similar** look and feel as *material* charts...

```
theme: 'material'
```

---

now the solution...

when attempting to use a Combo chart,
the points align to the y-axis, in between the two bars.
there is not an option that will allow the points to align **on** the bars.
so we must add the points manually, on the chart's `'ready'` event...

there are few chart [methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#methods) we need...

> `getChartLayoutInterface()` - Returns an object containing information about the onscreen placement of the chart and its elements.
>
> `getBoundingBox(id)` - Returns an object containing the left, top, width, and height of chart element id.
>
> `getXLocation(position, optional_axis_index)` - Returns the screen x-coordinate of position relative to the chart's container.

once the chart's `'ready'` event fires, we can get the layout interface using --> `getChartLayoutInterface()`

the other two methods mentioned above are methods of the layout interface.

we use `getBoundingBox(id)` to get the coordinates of the bar, on which the point will be placed.
this will give us the Y coordinate, and the height of the point.
the id of the bar is determined by the data row and series column.

```
bar#C#R  // where C is the series column index, and R is the row index
```

we are providing the X coordinate,
`getXLocation` will provide the location on the chart, needed to place the point on the x-axis, at our predetermined location.

```
// x coordinates of points to add
var points = [
  [36, 8],
  [28, 8],
  [10, 8],
];

// loop data rows and columns
for (var r = 0; r < data.getNumberOfRows(); r++) {
  for (var c = 1; c < data.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
    // calculate position of the point
    var barBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('bar#' + (c - 1) + '#' + r);
    var xCoord = chartLayout.getXLocation(points[r][c - 1]);
    var height = barBounds.height / 4;
    var top = barBounds.top + (height * 2);

    // create and add the point to the chart
    var point = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'circle');
    point.setAttribute('cx', xCoord);
    point.setAttribute('cy', top);
    point.setAttribute('r', height);
    point.setAttribute('stroke', '#ffffff');
    point.setAttribute('stroke-width', height);
    point.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
    svg.appendChild(point);
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
var chart;

google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function drawStuff() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Y', 'Series 1', 'Series 2'],
    ['Element A', 44, 11],
    ['Element B', 31, 11],
    ['Element C', 12, 11],
  ]);

  // x coordinates of points to add
  var points = [
    [36, 8],
    [28, 8],
    [10, 8],
  ];

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      left: 128,
      top: 24,
      right: 128,
      bottom: 72,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'X'
    },
    height: '100%',
    theme: 'material',
    vAxis: {
      title: data.getColumnLabel(0)
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  var div = document.getElementById('top_x_div');
  //var link = document.getElementById('url');

  chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(div);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // get chart layour interface and svg
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var svg = div.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;

    // loop data rows and columns
    for (var r = 0; r < data.getNumberOfRows(); r++) {
      for (var c = 1; c < data.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
        // calculate position of the point
        var barBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('bar#' + (c - 1) + '#' + r);
        var xCoord = chartLayout.getXLocation(points[r][c - 1]);
        var height = barBounds.height / 4;
        var top = barBounds.top + (height * 2);

        // create and add the point to the chart
        var point = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'circle');
        point.setAttribute('cx', xCoord);
        point.setAttribute('cy', top);
        point.setAttribute('r', height);
        point.setAttribute('stroke', '#ffffff');
        point.setAttribute('stroke-width', height);
        point.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
        svg.appendChild(point);
      }
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
});
```

```css
#top_x_div {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="top_x_div"></div>
```

Comment: Woah! Your answer nailed it. polished up to the details. I was just trying to figure out some piece of code that would lead me to it but then you laid a complete whole working code. This is such a great help.

Comment: cheers! the code assumes a point will exist for every bar, may need to adjust if not the case...